# How to parse multiple XML data using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jquery-mobile, xml-parsing

I'm getting response in XML using Ajax call, i can parse the data but only a single data not multiple data elements, what i am getting in xml response is:

```
           <GetTimeSlotsForUserType_1Response>
             <GetTimeSlotsForUserType_1Result>
              <NewDataSet xmlns="">
              <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                 <SlotId>406</SlotId>
                 <TimeAvailable> 01:00</TimeAvailable>
                 <CutOffHours>0.50</CutOffHours>
                 <Sequence>1</Sequence>
              </Table>
              <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                 <SlotId>408</SlotId>
                 <TimeAvailable>02:00</TimeAvailable>
                 <CutOffHours>0.50</CutOffHours>
                 <Sequence>1</Sequence>
              </Table>
              <Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
                 <SlotId>410</SlotId>
                 <TimeAvailable>03:00</TimeAvailable>
                 <CutOffHours>0.50</CutOffHours>
                 <Sequence>1</Sequence>
              </Table>
              <Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
                 <SlotId>412</SlotId>
                 <TimeAvailable>04:00</TimeAvailable>
                 <CutOffHours>0.50</CutOffHours>
                 <Sequence>1</Sequence>
              </Table>
              <Table diffgr:id="Table5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
                 <SlotId>414</SlotId>
                 <TimeAvailable>05:00</TimeAvailable>
                 <CutOffHours>0.50</CutOffHours>
                 <Sequence>1</Sequence>
              </Table>
           </NewDataSet>
     </GetTimeSlotsForUserType_1Result>
  </GetTimeSlotsForUserType_1Response>
```

I need the various  elements and put them one by one in the Select menu in my HTML page.

Jquery code:

```
function GetTimeSlotsForUser(){
var soapMessage4='<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><GetTimeSlotsForUserType_1 xmlns="http://there.org/"><opFacId>'+ OpFacId +'</opFacId><requestType>'+ check +'</requestType><category>'+ category +'</category><availableFor>'+ issignee +'</availableFor></GetTimeSlotsForUserType_1></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

 $.ajax({
    url: "http://33.204.22.31/therewebservice/therewebservice.asmx?op=GetTimeSlotsForUserType_1",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    SOAPAction: "http://there.org/GetTimeSlotsForUserType_1",
    data: soapMessage4,
    complete: endSaveProduct4,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
       });

return false;
}

function endSaveProduct4(xmlHttpRequest,status){
var optionlist='<option value="select-value-2">-- Select Time --</option>';

$(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML)
.find('NewDataSet')
.each(function()
      {
      var timeAvailable=$(this).find('TimeAvailable').text();
      optionlist += '<option>' + timeAvailable + '</option>';

      });
$("#select-choice-2").html(optionlist).selectmenu('refresh', true);
}
```

Till here i am able to get the data in optionlist, but it just grab all the  elements and put it as a one option in my select menu like this...:

[image: You can see the data is coming in one single option, instead of different options]

What i want is to parse all the different "Time Available" elements from the xml and to display it as multiple options in select menu.
Please help.

Comment: If you felt that an reply answered your question mark it as the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
timeSlots = $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML).find('TimeAvailable')
$(timeSlots).each(function(){ 
    optionlist += '<option>' + $(this).text() + '</option>';
});
```

Comment: I am able to parse the XML but only in a SINGLE DATA ELEMENT, which is timeAvailable, but as you can see there are many timeAvailable elements and which is all i need. my code parses them all in one single line, i need some array or something else to store different timeAvailable elements and to show them in select menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use [OpenJS](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/xml_parser/) to parse XML to js object. Next steps are easy.

Comment: I am able to parse the XML but only in a SINGLE DATA ELEMENT, which is timeAvailable, but as you can see there are many timeAvailable elements and which is all i need. my code parses them all in one single line, i need some array or something else to store different timeAvailable elements and to show them in select menu.